# gmaps-api-issues after updateing to v23 of 'com.android.support:design' and 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'

Tags: android

My app worked fine for three months but when I moved to

```
'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

and added

```
apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I started getting crashed with stacktrace of unknown source:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.streetview.aa.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.streetview.ag.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.streetview.ag.run(Unknown Source)
```

and

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: left == right
        at android.opengl.Matrix.frustumM(Matrix.java:327)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.j(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.l(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.v.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.aw.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.cb.onTransact(SourceFile:82)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IProjectionDelegate$zza$zza.getVisibleRegion(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection.getVisibleRegion(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer$RenderTask.run(DefaultClusterRenderer.java:363)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

They don't seem to be connected in sense that one is about DefaultClusterRenderer and another about streetview but they started happening excatly at the same time.

I read about the second problems [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8724) as well.

Does anyone have a glue why this is happening or how to catch there errors?

Btw I am using `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

Comment: It may be related to this issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8724. However, I did not encounter the 'left == right' bug until I upgraded to version 24.0.2 of the support libraries.